# Contesting a surprise bill from Amazon

Tags: european-union, terms-of-service, consumer-protection

Today I got an email from Amazon asking me to pay a large amount of money for their services. I signed up on AWS two weeks ago to discover their platform, and tried following one of their tutorials. At no point did they disclose a price or indicate they will charge me. I gave my credit card info under the impression it was necessary for a free trial. I have contacted them with my grievances and am awaiting a reply.

Is there anything I can do to contest the bill? I am in the European Union, so hoping there is a law protecting consumers against such practices.

Comment: Have you asked Amazon to explain the charges? If so, what did they say?

Comment: I haven't asked for an explanation. I have a bill that lists some instances as "monthly free tier" as well as another expensive instance that I was not aware of.

Comment: Someone started that expensive instance in your account. Are you sure it wasn't you?

Comment: I signed up on their website where they advertise you can get started for free. Then I followed one of their beginner tutorials, and haven't logged back on since then. There was no price shown on the tutorial or the interface I interacted with.

Comment: Are you a scam victim? I get frequent fake emails (and phone calls) that *aren't* from Amazon. When does Amazon not ask for payment up front?

Comment: @WeatherVane They never ask instance payments up front. It's always after the usage. OP, it would help to explain the exact instance or even cite the  bill.

Comment: *I signed up on their website where they advertise you can get started for free.* - you signed a contract.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the particular service sign-up? I don't get why they emailed you for payment, when you say you already provided the card details.

Comment: The website is aws.amazon.com

Comment: ...to the *particular* service. That page has "Free trials", "12 months free" and "Always free". Do we have to guess what the T&C are? Nobody can answer without knowing exactly what you signed up for. Amazon Prime also offers a free trial, but it is only the subscription that is free. I recently had a free 3-month trial for a Google service. I was charged nothing to my card (stayed within the usage limits), and the account statements arrived by email. Were you asked to pay by email (you already gave the card details), or was it an account statement?

Comment: I wasn't thorough enough when I signed up, seems like even though you sign up for free, you have costs in some cases depending on what services you use. That information wasn't clear to me at all, I was under the impression my account was limited to free-tier services exclusively. So I signed up, tried a tutorial, and forgot about it for two weeks.

Comment: I received a payment overdue notification by email. The cost is due to a SageMaker instance that I have now deleted.